# Script for setting CountDown timer and Canvas does not play properly in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr

I'm building a first person VR shooting game and the script responsible for CountDown and displaying Canvas on which Play Again Button appears does not play..

Here is the screen of the game play and the script for better understanding:

[image: GamePlay]

```
`

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class playGameAgainScript : MonoBehaviour {

    //Use this for Timer
    public Text countDown;
    private float timer = 60;

    //Declare Button
    public Button playAgainButton;

    void Start() {
        //Set countDown value
        countDown = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void Update() {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        countDown.text = "" + timer.ToString ("f0");
        if (timer <= 0) {
            timer = 0;
            playAgainButton.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        } 
    }

    public void PlayAgain() {
        UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene ("Main Scene");
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Why do you have a button component and also a EventTrigger? Does your canvas has a GraphicsRaycaster?

Comment: Because I needed a PointerEnter functionality.. Yes, the canvas has a GraphicsRaycaster..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the playGameAgainButton was set to inactive as default and therefore the editor had nothing to look for..
And by moving the functionality from this script to a different place, it solved the probblem.. I moved it to the main playerScript and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code you provided a little bit and hope that it works

```
 private bool counting=true,
 void Update() {
if(counting){
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        countDown.text = "" + timer.ToString ("f0");
        if (timer <= 0f) {
            counting=false;
            playAgainButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
}
}
```

notice that in your code the condition of timer<=0 is always valid when you make timer=0;
now it will enter just one time to the condition and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that is not the problem.. I get what you did there but the code seems to be working fine..
It just dont get instantiated i feel.. Unity doesn't throw error but the countDown(that 60 in red) doesn't start..

Comment: Ok,try to remove  countDown = GetComponent<Text>(); from the Start function and assign it manually.

Comment: The problem was that the playGameAgainButton was set to inactive as default and therefore the editor had nothing to look for.. And by moving the functionality from this script to a different place, it solved the probblem.. I moved it to the main playerScript and it works fine.
Thanks anyway!